# ServiceStack: How to tell if a return from a request was cached?

Tags: c#, caching, servicestack

I have the caching hooked up in my request, but I'd like to be able to tell if the return I'm getting back is actually coming from the cache or not. Is there a way to see this? I have access to the code-base to make modifications.

ServiceStack's standard caching pattern:

```
public class OrdersService : Service
{
    public object Get(CachedOrders request)
    {
        var cacheKey = "unique_key_for_this_request";
        return base.RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(base.Cache,cacheKey,()=> 
            {
                //Delegate is executed if item doesn't exist in cache 
                //Any response DTO returned here will be cached automatically
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the caching code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in your comments the delegate passed to the `ToOptimizedResultUsingCache` method is only executed if the item doesn't exist in the cache. I would just add a "cached at" property to the response DTO and set it in that delegate.

```
public class OrdersService : Service
{
    public object Get(CachedOrders request)
    {
        var cacheKey = "unique_key_for_this_request";
        var returnDto = base.RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(base.Cache,cacheKey,() => {
            return new MyReturnDto {
                CachedAt = DateTime.Now
            };                
        });
    }
}
```

You can then use the `CachedAt` property to see when the item was cached.

If you don't want to modify your DTO you can just use a variable outside of the scope of delegate called when caching the result.

```
public class OrdersService : Service
{
    public object Get(CachedOrders request)
    {
        var cacheKey = "unique_key_for_this_request";
        var isCached = false;
        var returnDto = base.RequestContext.ToOptimizedResultUsingCache(base.Cache,cacheKey,() => {
            isCached = true;             
        });
        // Do something if it was cached...
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've read (from mythz) that adding non-business related data to DTOs defeats a core practice of services in ServiceStack. And adding a CachedAt property to all of my business objects isn't something I'd like to do. 

I'd prefer if there were simply some way to detect from within my AppHost or ServiceStack runtime to see if a response is from a cache or not.

Comment: Your latest edit was a good idea. Can add a key/value pair to the base.Request.Items collection when the return is cached. Then from my AppHost I can look up the key from the Items collection to and do my logic there.